# How to get chain of all connected edges on DAG (pandas\networkx)

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

i have DAG that i'am convert to pandas_DF

the DF is:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'dad':[1, 2, 3, 4,5, "T1", "T2"],
          'children':["T1","T1","T2","T2",6,"T3","T3"]})
print (df)
```

i want to get list of all the nodes\edges that connected in my DAG (graph)
so it will look like this

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'dad':[1, 2, 3, 4,5, "T1", "T2","T3"],
          'children':["T1","T1","T2","T2",6,"T3","T3","X"],
           'chain':[0,0,0,0,0,[1,2],[3,4],[1,2,3,4,"T1","T2"]] })
```

i like to know the connection between the edges all over the chain, like the new column "chain" . its can be a new column like here ,and the order is not important too

i use pandas and networkx, but i will be happy to know a new library of DAG like networkx for python.

The graph looks like it has 2 trees inside
[image]

Comment: Have a look a `networkx`.

Comment: i look at networkx documentation but i did not find Nothing

Answer (score 4):

You can use `networkx` as @QuangHoang suggests like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

df=pd.DataFrame({'dad':[1, 2, 3, 4,5, "T1", "T2"],
          'children':["T1","T1","T2","T2",6,"T3","T3"]})
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'dad','children', create_using=nx.DiGraph())
df['chain'] = df['dad'].transform(lambda x: list(G.predecessors(x)))
df
```

Output:

```
  dad children   chain
0   1       T1      []
1   2       T1      []
2   3       T2      []
3   4       T2      []
4   5        6      []
5  T1       T3  [1, 2]
6  T2       T3  [3, 4]
```

---

I think you need all the components of the DiGraph... here is a way to generate those subgraphs with chains.

```
import pandas as  pd
import networkx as nx

df=pd.DataFrame({'dad':[1, 2, 3, 4,5, "T1", "T2"],
          'children':["T1","T1","T2","T2",6,"T3","T3"]})
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'dad','children', create_using=nx.DiGraph())
df['chain'] = df['dad'].transform(lambda x: list(G.predecessors(x)))


w_list = list(nx.weakly_connected_components(G))
df_comp = pd.DataFrame({'dad': [list(n)[-1] for n in w_list], 
              'children':['X' for _ in w_list], 
              'chain': [list(x) for x in w_list]})

df_out = pd.concat([df, df_comp])
df_out
```

Output:

```
  dad children                     chain
0   1       T1                        []
1   2       T1                        []
2   3       T2                        []
3   4       T2                        []
4   5        6                        []
5  T1       T3                    [1, 2]
6  T2       T3                    [3, 4]
0  T3        X  [1, 2, 3, 4, T1, T2, T3]
1   6        X                    [5, 6]
```

Comment: is ok but i like to have all the chain , but here you do not have the df["chain"] ["T3"][[1,2,3,4,"T1","T2"]]

Comment: @matan Scott's answer is what you are aksing for. It's just two sample data you presented in the questions are different.

Comment: @matan what about 5,6?

Comment: 5 and 6 is a small tree, which is not linked to the big tree

Comment: @matan Okay.. well you can deal with that tree as you wish.  I hope this anwer has helped you sufficiently.  Please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=votes#tab-top) if you are satisfied.

Comment: i try you'r cod 
it's look good but i get Error

df=pd.DataFrame({'dad':[1, 2, 3, 4,5, "T1", "T2"],
          'children':["T1","T1","T2","T2",6,"T3","T3"]})
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'dad','children', create_using=nx.DiGraph())
df['chain'] = df['dad'].transform(lambda x: list(G.predecessors(x)))

df_comp = pd.DataFrame({'dad': [list(n)[-1] for n in w_list], 
              'children':['X' for _ in w_list], 
              'chain': [list(x) for x in list(nx.weakly_connected_components(G))]})

df_out = pd.concat([df, df_comp])

ValueError: arrays must all be same length

Comment: This code runs fine in my environment.   May that ValueError is coming from a different place.

Comment: 'w_list' is not defined

Comment: @matan Ah... `w_list = list(nx.weakly_connected_components(G))`  My apologies.    I forgot that line of code.  Sorry.

Comment: Thank you.
Now it works but for some reason 5,6 are also connected to X
you can see by the graph  that is not the same tree.

Comment: X is just a place holder.  There no in that tree.  Feel free to modify that code to place anything you want in there.  X1 and X2?

Comment: Thanks you, I found it very helpful